# I either don't get any messages from a web socket (socket.io), or occasionally I get them all at once (but not always)

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

When I start my server, I get 1 response from the web socket that shows information about bitcoin but I either never get updates whenever the price changes or I suddenly get loads of updates. I assume I should be getting a new message every second or so. I'm using this web socket https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/#-api-web-socket-current-

Here's my code:

```
var ioClient = require('socket.io-client');
var cryptocompare = ioClient.connect('wss://streamer.cryptocompare.com')

var subscription = '2~Poloniex~BTC~USD';
cryptocompare.emit('SubAdd', { subs: [subscription] });
cryptocompare.on('error', console.error)
cryptocompare.on('m', function(message) {
    console.log(message);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first instance I would very strongly encourage you to use the Tidwall websockets library

https://github.com/tidwall/SwiftWebSocket

It's incredibly well-written, it's one of the best libraries of any type out there.

Again in the first instance, you'll struggle to know what is going on, until you are using a rock-solid library ...